# I want to print change in my date slider I created with plotly and dash using animation and frames

Tags: python, animation, plotly, slider, dashboard

I want to capture the date my slider is at. In other words, any change in the date slider should be printed in my compiler. Look at this code:
This is a bit lengthy but simple and 'run-able' code. The data is within it

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

years = ["1952", "1962", "1967", "1972", "1977", "1982", "1987", "1992", "1997", "2002",
         "2007"]

# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset["continent"]:
    if continent not in continents:
        continents.append(continent)
# make figure
fig_dict = {
    "data": [],
    "layout": {},
    "frames": []
}

# fill in most of layout
fig_dict["layout"]["xaxis"] = {"range": [30, 85], "title": "Life Expectancy"}
fig_dict["layout"]["yaxis"] = {"title": "GDP per Capita", "type": "log"}
fig_dict["layout"]["hovermode"] = "closest"
fig_dict["layout"]["updatemenus"] = [
    {
        "buttons": [
            {
                "args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": False},
                                "fromcurrent": True, "transition": {"duration": 300,
                                                                    "easing": "quadratic-in-out"}}],
                "label": "Play",
                "method": "animate"
            },
            {
                "args": [[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
                                  "mode": "immediate",
                                  "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                "label": "Pause",
                "method": "animate"
            }
        ],
        "direction": "left",
        "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 87},
        "showactive": False,
        "type": "buttons",
        "x": 0.1,
        "xanchor": "right",
        "y": 0,
        "yanchor": "top"
    }
]

sliders_dict = {
    "active": 0,
    "yanchor": "top",
    "xanchor": "left",
    "currentvalue": {
        "font": {"size": 20},
        "prefix": "Year:",
        "visible": True,
        "xanchor": "right"
    },
    "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
    "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 50},
    "len": 0.9,
    "x": 0.1,
    "y": 0,
    "steps": []
}

# make data
year = 1952
for continent in continents:
    dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset["year"] == year]
    dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[
        dataset_by_year["continent"] == continent]

    data_dict = {
        "x": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["lifeExp"]),
        "y": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["gdpPercap"]),
        "mode": "markers",
        "text": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["country"]),
        "marker": {
            "sizemode": "area",
            "sizeref": 200000,
            "size": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["pop"])
        },
        "name": continent
    }
    fig_dict["data"].append(data_dict)

# make frames
for year in years:
    frame = {"data": [], "name": str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset["year"] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[
            dataset_by_year["continent"] == continent]

        data_dict = {
            "x": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["lifeExp"]),
            "y": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["gdpPercap"]),
            "mode": "markers",
            "text": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["country"]),
            "marker": {
                "sizemode": "area",
                "sizeref": 200000,
                "size": list(dataset_by_year_and_cont["pop"])
            },
            "name": continent
        }
        frame["data"].append(data_dict)

    fig_dict["frames"].append(frame)
    slider_step = {"args": [
        [year],
        {"frame": {"duration": 300, "redraw": False},
         "mode": "immediate",
         "transition": {"duration": 300}}
    ],
        "label": year,
        "method": "animate"}
    sliders_dict["steps"].append(slider_step)


fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"] = [sliders_dict]

fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)

fig.show()
```

You will see years on the slider. Whether its animated or dragged with the mouse, I wish to see the year my slider is at in the compiler, just like a print function.

The larger scope of this problem:
I am working on a similar problem related to a project. My aim to print the updated date is to access the current date. I have other plots to create and they depend on the updated date.

Thanks

Comment: Next time please reduce the code to a minimum example.

Comment: apologies for long code. I understand. But this has been a nightmare for me for a couple of week now. I did not want to leave any stone unturned

Comment: What do you call "my compiler" ? The figure is rendered by the client using Plotly.js and all events (ie. including slider change and plot updates) occur clientside, in the browser. There is a way to handle slider events by embedding some javascript into your code, but you won't be able to reach the python backend on slider change - unless you have a server running. So if you absolutely need to handle those events and create the other plots that depend on it in python, just use [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/). If it's ok for you to do that in js/Plotly.js, let me know.

Comment: Another way is possible using figure widgets, but it implies rendering the plots in a notebook.

Comment: Hi EricLavault!
I meant the 'console' Thanks for correction. I wish to keep it on plotly.js. And just want to grab that updated "date" on the slider. I will be thankful if you could provide me with the code snippet to grab it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interactive renderers display figures using Plotly.js, you can actually *use* Javascript+Plotly.js to hook into the `plotly_sliderchange` event to achieve what you want. You just need to pass the javascript code as a string to plotly's `Figure.show()` method via the `post_script` parameter.

We use the placeholder `'{plot_id}'` for identifying the graph div whose id is generated in this case. The javascript snippet(s) are executed just after plot creation.

```py
fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)

js = '''
const gd = document.getElementById('{plot_id}');

gd.on('plotly_sliderchange', function(eventData) {
    // console.log(eventData);

    const slider = eventData.slider; // the slider emitting the event
    const step = eventData.step;     // the currently active step
    const year = step.value;         // the current year

    console.log(year);
});
'''
""

fig.show(post_script=[js])
```

[image: output gif]

Note we can also pass a post script when using the methods [`to_html()`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.to_html) or [`write_html()`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.write_html).

See also [Event Handlers in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#using-plotlyjs-events).

Comment: Hi! I copy pasted this code after fig = go.Figure(fig_dict). And ran it. It still does not give the date I click on slider at my console! I just want to grab this current_date.

Comment: It's in there with all other information about the slider and the current step. See revised answer.

Comment: Eric, Is it possible to get this in my python console? because thats where I want to get it into a variable! BTW, amazing work. You have almost did it for me and my team:D

Comment: Can you reread the comment I left under your question and your answer to that comment ?

Comment: I think that the misunderstanding comes from "console". By console, I meant my Pycharm's console. For an instance, when I write print("Hello Python") in PyCharm or VSCode, it prints me the out there. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: though we are still a bit away from having it from our vscode/pycharm console, I thank you for letting us come this close. :)

Comment: As mentioned earlier, _you won't be able to reach the python backend on slider change **unless you have a server running**_, or, _another way is possible using figure widgets, but it implies rendering the plots in a **notebook**_. Also, it's not clear whether you are using Dash+Plotly.py or just Plotly.py (the question title is "I want to print change in my date slider I created with **plotly and dash**"), the code you shared suggest you are just using Plotly.py. Dash actually runs a server and provide callbacks where you could log data on slider change in your vscode console.

Comment: I think I could help further if you explain what you are planning to do with the figure/slider (is it just a one-shot/standalone viewer for exploring data, or do you plan to host some web app that displays charts, or is it for integrating into an existing app..)

Comment: Um alright, so we have several spots (location) on which our sensors are installed. We created reports on a daily basis. In report, there is some data about every sensor that keeps changing every day. I made a compilation of all reports and visualized them over "go.scatter_mapbox" and several other things. In my actual data, the slider has date over it

Comment: I want to capture that date and store it into a variable.

Comment: This will be a plotly+dash app deployed on a server. At this moment, we can't get date from the slider. I want to capture this date because it will trigger some other plots as well.

Comment: In this case I suggest you ask a new question that includes the relevant part of your Dash app (layout and callbacks). If you didn't start this part yet, I suggest you do it right now, because you will likely end up using a [`dcc.Slider`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider) and use Dash [callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) to animate and monitor the current date value among many many other things. I mean you will eventually drop plotly layout sliders and updatemenus.

Comment: To better illustrate what I mean, see https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing (this is the Part 3 of the Dash Fundamentals, it's worth taking the time to read the 4 parts before starting!).

Comment: The biggest issue with that approach is the lack of "Play/Pause" button! Do you think that there is a smooth way to add an animation effect with "Play/Pause" effect?

Comment: Yes you can still animate the graph but differently: add the buttons to the layout, and bind them to callbacks. For example, the play button callback could be a clientside callback that runs [`Plotly.animate()`](https://plotly.com/javascript/animations/). Or, it could just enable a [`dcc.Interval`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component which, once running, triggers a sequence of slider updates, the slider having a callback that updates the graph, and the graph component having animation properties. There are several ways to achieve that.

Comment: Great, having some confidence received from you, I am definitely going to try it out. :D

Comment: Hi Eric, Could you kindly review question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77170666/hi-i-am-facing-trouble-with-animating-plotly-figure-with-dash-slider-along-with

Answer (score 0):

You need to "attach" an observation to the slider.

```
N_slider = IntSlider(min=0, max=20, step=1, value=3)

def view(change):
    print(change.new)

N_slider.observe(view, names='value')

N_slider
```

Comment: Hi!  Could you tell me where this IntSlider comes from?

And how to incorporate this in my code?