# Hi! I am facing trouble with animating plotly figure with dash slider along with play/pause functionality

Tags: python, slider, plotly-dash

In the following code, you will find that I want to show my data about some locations (also known as "Spots") on a plotly's scatter_mapbox.
**The "Values" updates every day. Whereas "spotName" remain constant.**

So the plan is:

- to show "spotName" over a plotly's scatter_mapbox as markers.
- to show "Value" as color of the marker.
- to show "Date" on dash's slider.

This has been roughly done in the code below. However, to add an animation effect, I want to add a play/pause button. If I play it, the date on slider should wait for 2 seconds on each slider and then move on to the next date itself. Similarly, pause should pause it there. Essentially, the same play pause that we have in videos.

I tried to build animation effect on the slider but failed. Even if a play/pause button is added, it did not work correctly.

Here is the code you may begin with:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import time

# Defining locations of the spots
dict_loc = {'A': [33.68990417084562, 73.01930394525846],
            'B': [33.689937996632274, 73.019363570343],
            'C': [33.6897207596818, 73.01940241698901],
            'D': [33.68975233048378, 73.01946204207356]}

# Load your sample DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01',
             '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02',
             '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03',
             '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04',
             '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05'],
    'spotName': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Value': [0, 1, 2, 0,
              1, 2, 3, 1,
              2, 0, 4, 2,
              3, 1, 5, 0,
              4, 2, 0, 1], })

# Map latitude and longitude values from dict_loc based on 'spotName' column
data['latitude'] = data['spotName'].map(lambda x: dict_loc[x][0])
data['longitude'] = data['spotName'].map(lambda x: dict_loc[x][1])

# Create a unique integer identifier for each date
date_to_int = {date: i for i, date in enumerate(data['Date'].unique())}

# Map the integer identifier to the 'Date' column
data['DateInt'] = data['Date'].map(date_to_int)

# Define the color map
color_map = {
    0: 'blue',
    1: 'magenta',
    2: 'lime',
    3: 'orange',
    4: 'red',
    5: 'black'
}

# Use a lambda function to map values to colors, using 'black' as the default
# Map values to colors using the color_map dictionary
data['color_map'] = data['Value'].map(color_map)

# Create the Dash app and layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='map-graph'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='date-slider',
        min=min(data['DateInt']),
        max=max(data['DateInt']),
        step=1,  # Change step to 1 for smoother animation
        marks={i: date for date, i in date_to_int.items()},
        value=min(data['DateInt'])
    ),
    html.Button('Play', id='play-button', n_clicks=0),
    # Hidden div to store map state
    html.Div(id='map-state', style={'display': 'none'}),
    dcc.Interval(id='animation-interval', interval=2000, n_intervals=0)  # 1000 ms (1 second)
])

# Initialize variables for animation
current_slider_value = min(data['DateInt'])

animation_paused = True
# Initialize a variable to keep track of the last printed date
last_printed_date = None


# Define a callback to update the map based on the selected date
@app.callback(
    [Output('map-graph', 'figure'),
     Output('map-state', 'children'),
     Output('date-slider', 'value')],
    [Input('date-slider', 'value'),
     Input('map-graph', 'relayoutData'),
     Input('play-button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('animation-interval', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_map(selected_date_int, relayout_data, play_button_clicks, n_intervals):
    global current_slider_value, animation_paused, last_printed_date

    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]

    if changed_id == 'play-button.n_clicks':
        # Play button is clicked
        animation_paused = not animation_paused

    if not animation_paused:
        # Increment the slider value
        current_slider_value += 1

        if current_slider_value > max(data['DateInt']):
            current_slider_value = min(data['DateInt'])

    selected_date = [date for date, i in date_to_int.items() if i == current_slider_value][0]
    filtered_data = data[data['Date'] == selected_date]

    # Get the current map state
    map_state = relayout_data if relayout_data else {}

    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add scatter points to the map
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=filtered_data['latitude'],
        lon=filtered_data['longitude'],
        text=filtered_data['spotName'],
        marker=dict(
            size=15,
            color=filtered_data['color_map'],
        )
    ))

    fig.update_layout(
        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
        mapbox_zoom=map_state.get('mapbox.zoom', 18),  # Use current zoom level or default to 18
        mapbox_center=map_state.get('mapbox.center', {"lat": 33.68990417084562, "lon": 73.01930394525846}),
    )

    # Print the current 'Date' value to the console if it has changed
    current_date = [date for date, i in date_to_int.items() if i == selected_date_int][0]
    if current_date != last_printed_date:
        print(f"Selected Date: {current_date}")
        last_printed_date = current_date

    return fig, map_state, current_slider_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Note that scatter markers in a mapbox trace won't update smoothly as it does in a simple scatter trace, even if using animation frames with transition parameters. Also, it seems only the "Value", that is, the marker color, will change over time (as the spots remains the same whatever the date) so the absence of smoothness might not be a problem ? For the code, I suggest you use multiple callbacks: 1. update the graph given a slider value input, 2. start/stop the animation (enable/disable dcc.Interval), 3. animate slider value given the n_intervals inputs (which will in turn trigger 1.)